# How to export the generated theme in the Material Plugin for Sketch?

Tags: android, material-design, android-theme, sketch-3, material-components-android

We are using the Material Design Theme Editor Plugin in Sketch. It's a fantastic tool because it allows us to follow the Material Design guidelines very easily and to have a visual consistency in our apps. But I can't find an option to export the generated theme for Android, iOS, Flutter or Web.

Currently, I am more concerned with the generated theme for Android.

So, is it possible to export the generated theme for Android in a xml file from the Material Plugin for Sketch?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the plugin doesn't support that. If you are looking for alternatives, [Panache](https://rxlabz.github.io/panache_web/#/) is a new tool for creating themes for Flutter which you can then download and drop directly into your code.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible. Sketch doesn't currently support exporting as XML.